# How to redirect the user to the home page?

Tags: 8, redirection

When users access the site, they are redirected to their user account page. I want to redirect them to the front page. If I leave the *Default front page* setting empty, users are redirect to their account page, while the description for the setting says they would be redirected to the front page.

> [image: screenshot]

In this field, you must put */node* to display the front page.

I know there are modules to do this, but I would like to avoid installing additional modules. Is there a configuration to achieve what I want, in Drupal 8.9.3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the site root page to a landing page instead of user login?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294068/how-can-i-set-the-site-root-page-to-a-landing-page-instead-of-user-login)

Comment: Default front page when left empty is /user/login which when logged in gets you to your account page. To redirect users upon login to the front page has been answered many times before. There also are modules for that. Try to google for: Drupal 8 login redirect front page.

Comment: User login always redirects to user account - this setting would not affect that anyway.

Comment: Okay well, we cannot force that. You could post an issue in the project queue for core if it's not there already.

Comment: You can always use the destination query parameter to redirect people after logging in. Create a login link with url like: `/user/login?destination=/my/custom/url/for/logged/in/users`

Comment: That setting is for the default front page. The description doesn't say the users will always be redirected to that page. In fact, many forms redirect users to a different page. For example, the user login form redirects users to their user account page, as @Kevin said.

Comment: The help text makes no claim about where users will go after they log in. Nor is there anything anywhere that says a user will be directed to the homepage after logging in. These are assumptions that you've made on your own. That field is there to define the page that will be displayed when a user hits your site's main url, e.g. example.com. In your case, you want /node to be the front page, so that's the url you would enter there. Someone else may want /my-cool-homepage to be the front page, so that's what they would enter.

Comment: I tested it on a plain installation on simplytest.me: When I log in, I am redirected to the account page. After the login, if I visit `https://test-site`, I am redirected to the default front page, which is node/1, the one saying _No front page content has been created yet. Follow the User Guide to start building your site._

Comment: Yes, it's a bit confusing that the default value for the default front page is different from the default value for the default front page used from the default installation profile Drupal uses when it's installed. Probably not calling the settings _Default front page_ would help to make it less confusing.

Comment: Hi, i have the same issue I try to use a module for after login and destroy my admin access, force me to reinstall my site, drupal not have a solution for a redirect the user to the landing page or home page? for example /user/login?destination=/front?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Drupal considers the default front page is not /node, but /user/login, which redirects logged-in users to their account page. [`SiteInformationForm::validateForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Form%21SiteInformationForm.php/function/SiteInformationForm%3A%3AvalidateForm/8.9.x) contains the following code.

```
  // Check for empty front page path.
  if ($form_state->isValueEmpty('site_frontpage')) {

    // Set to default "user/login".
    $form_state->setValueForElement($form['front_page']['site_frontpage'], '/user/login');
  }
```

*site_frontpage* is the form element for the front page, which in [`SiteInformationForm::buildForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Form%21SiteInformationForm.php/function/SiteInformationForm%3A%3AbuildForm/8.9.x) is set as follows.

```
  $front_page = $site_config->get('page.front') != '/user/login' ? $this->aliasManager->getAliasByPath($site_config->get('page.front')) : '';
  $form['front_page']['site_frontpage'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Default front page'),
    '#default_value' => $front_page,
    '#size' => 40,
    '#description' => t('Optionally, specify a relative URL to display as the front page. Leave blank to display the default front page.'),
    '#field_prefix' => $this->requestContext->getCompleteBaseUrl(),
  ];
```

Note that the Standard installation profile set the default front page to /node, in its system.site.yml file. Don't take that as the default front page. It's the default value assigned from that installation profile to the *Default front page* setting.

```yaml
uuid: ''
name: ''
mail: ''
slogan: ''
page:
  403: ''
  404: ''
  front: /node
admin_compact_mode: false
weight_select_max: 100
langcode: en
default_langcode: en
```

Comment: This code works for drupal 9.2?

Comment: The configuration I show would work also for Drupal 9.x.